# How to dynamically change the number of columns while resizing a QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qabstractitemmodel

Is it possible to change the number of columns in a QTableView when user dynamically resize the QTableView? For example I have 9 images of number 1-9, I have a QTableView with custom delegate that paint the image into the cell of the table, I would like the QTableView to behave like the way in following picture:

[image: Imgur]

What should be my direction and how should I implement it?

Comment: It looks like you need more a layout than a view don't you ? There is [flow layout example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html) in C++ and a native [flow layout in QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html).

Comment: Alternatively you might want to look at using a [`QListView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html) with [`viewMode`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#viewMode-prop) set to `QListView::IconMode` and [`flow`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistview.html#flow-prop) set to `QListView::LeftToRight`.

Comment: Do you have a model for your table view? You can handle resize event of your table, pass the current table width to the model and let it to calculate the number of columns. This approach, however, brakes the MVC pattern, i.e. model should not depend on the view.

Comment: @G.M. I will adopt your solution, thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code for the solution:

```
QListViewIconModeLtoRFlow::QListViewIconModeLtoRFlow(QWidget *parent): QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    QFrame *frame = new QFrame;
    QVBoxLayout *main = new QVBoxLayout(frame);

    QListView *list = new QListView;
    list->setFlow(QListView::LeftToRight);
    list->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
    list->setViewMode(QListView::IconMode);
    list->setIconSize(QSize(50,50));

    QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel;
    list->setModel(model);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    {
        QPixmap p("F:\\boro.jpg");
        QIcon *icon = new QIcon(p);
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(*icon, NULL); //NULL to hide string appearance
        model->appendRow(item);
    }
    main->addWidget(list);
    setCentralWidget(frame);
}
```

A text will appear below the icon if QStandardItem is constructed as usual:

[image: Imgur]

Pass NULL as the QString parameter instead:

[image: Imgur]